# Sync Checkmarks Between UISearchController and FetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to sync `accessoryType.Checkmark` between a search view and non-search view. I've tried setting `cell.accessoryType = .None` in a few different spots on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, yet I keep getting random checkmarks when I switch between `fetchedResults` and search results. I don't know what I'm screwing up, but I rest assured it'll be something startlingly stupid.

I have a `UITableViewController` that's set up. When it loads, I have it configured to display items from a `NSFetchRequest`. It works perfectly.

I have a `UISearchController` that's also set up. It works perfectly and displays the results I want.

I encounter the problem of random checkmarks appearing when I toggle between the search and fetchRequest. My array of stuff to save is working perfectly and the right items are in there---it's the checkmarks that are getting ****ed up. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I'm out of ideas.

Here are the relevant properties I've got declared before `viewDidLoad` in my `UITableViewController` class:

```
// Create array to dump fetchResults
var unfilteredJingles = [Jingle]()

// Create array to store filtered search results
var filteredJingles = [Jingle]()

// Array where ones I want to save get added/removed
var jinglesToSave = [Jingle]()

// resultsSearchController
var resultsSearchController = UISearchController()
```

When cells are selected, I have `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` configured to do two things:

1) append the `jinglesToSave` for that cell to an array and place a checkmark next to the cell. This works.

2) remove a `jinglesToSave` for that cell from the `jinglesToSave` array. This works, too.

The issue I'm encountering is random cells getting checked when I switch between `searchResultsController.active` and `searchResultsController` NOT active. The correct cells are staying checked, but random ones sometimes get checked.

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("jingleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // instantiate a local array and assign it to filtered/unfiltered results based on whether
    // the resultsSearchController is active
    var jingleArray = [Jingle]()

    if resultsSearchController.active {
        // set local array to the filtered array
        jingleArray = filteredJingles
        let jingle = jingleArray[indexPath.row]
        // Set labels for cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = jingle.jingleDescription
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = jingle.jingleStar

    } else {
        // set the local array to the UN-filtered array
        jingleArray = unfilteredJingles
        // Get the jingle for the index
        let jingle = jingleArray[indexPath.row]
        // Set labels for cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = jingle.jingleDescription
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = jingle.jingleStar
    }

    // Set checkmarks
    if self.jinglesToSave.count > 0 {
        // enumerate jinglesToSave...
        for (indexOfJinglesToSave, jingleToSave) in jinglesToSave.enumerate() {
            // if the object in the array of stuff to save matches the object in the index of the tableview
            if jingleArray[indexPath.row].hashValue == jinglesToSave[indexOfJinglesToSave].hashValue {
                // then set its accessoryView to checkmark
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the cells checkmark state to the default state (im guessing no checkmark) after you dequeue the cell. Its probably a cell recycling issue that the checkmarks are appearing on cells it shouldnt be on.

Comment: just after `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` put like `cell.accessoryType = .None` (or whatever it should be)

Comment: Me right now--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS7Og1zvdy8 THANK YOU!!! I tried setting the `accessoryType` elsewhere in that method, but I was doing it in the wrong place.